# Behavior of a sequence such that $e^{a_n}>ne^{a_{n+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $e^{a_n}>ne^{a_{n+1}}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, determine the behavior of $(a_n)_n$.

My approach: since $e^{a_n}>ne^{a_{n+1}}$ it  follows, applying the natural logarithm on both sides, that $a_n>\ln n + a_{n+1}$.

Since $\ln n>0$ for all $n\geq2$, it follows that $a_n>\ln n + a_{n+1}>a_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq2$; so $a_n$ is monotonic decreasing and then it has a limit $l$.

Lets now consider the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, we have that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<\frac{a_{n+1}}{\ln n + a_{n+1}}<\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}}=1$$

For all $n\geq2$, so for the ratio test $(a_n)_n$ is convergent.

Is it right?
I suspect it is wrong because the limit of the ratio could be $\leq1$ and not $<1$.

Comment: $a_n > \log(n) + a_{n+1} \iff a_{n+1} - a_n < -\log(n)$. Adding up these inequalities for $n = 1,... N-1$ gives $ a_N - a_1 < - \sum_{n = 1}^{N-1} \log(n) = \log((N-1)!)$. Clearly $(N-1)! \to \infty$ with $N$, so this tells us that $a_N \searrow -\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is not correct. Let $a_n =-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\log k+\frac 1 n$. then the inequality holds but $\lim a_n =-\infty$.

However if $a_n$ are positive then it is easy to see that $a_n$ is decreasing, hence convergent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me where is the error?

Comment: Your inequalities are valid only when $a_n$'s are positive. @Dunkelheit